# Variance of prediction doesn't match input data with Keras model

Tags: keras, regression

I'm using Keras to do a regression on inputs. I've tried a lot of different models, and a lot of them converge around the same place. My problem is with the distributions of the results. In order to validate the model, I compared the distribution of the input data (test and validation) with predictions on the same data. My data is distributed normally, so when I'd see predictions with a bimodal or uniform distribution, even when the loss looked good, I knew something wasn't working with the model.

I'm able to get a normal distribution (like my ground truth outputs). My problem is that the variance of the predictions is always smaller. My only guess is the loss function, but `MeanAbsoluteError` seemed like a better choice than mean squared for not distorting the output.

Here's the model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(32, activation="selu", kernel_initializer="lecun_normal", input_shape=(len(np_inputs[0]),)),
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    layers.Dense(32, activation="selu", kernel_initializer="lecun_normal"),
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(1, activation="tanh"),
])

model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(),
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
)
```

And histograms of the outputs. The buckets are the same size.

#### Training+validation outputs

[image]

#### Predictions based on training+validation

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "training *outputs*"? If you mean the ground truth (true values), please edit & update your post accordingly to clarify this (the term "outputs" in itself is ambiguous).

Comment: Updated. I also tried a few more things, and found that it will happy overfit to the correct distribution, so I suspect it's not doing a good job predicting, so predictions cluster around zero to minimize error.